# gtag.js not sending custom dimension data

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I configured gtag like:

```
  gtag('config', GA_TRACKING_ID, {
    custom_map: {
      dimension1: 'language',
      dimension2: 'section'
    },
  });
```

In GA, I have:

[image]

But when I look into the Chrome Debugger, language and section are not sent, why is that?

I am calling gtag like:

```
      gtag('event', 'viewpdf', {
        event_category: 'engagement',
        event_action: 'viewpdf',
        event_label: name,
        language: language,
        section: section
      })
```

Comment: I run a similar config and it works. What are the language and section variables set to in your last example?

Comment: @PhilipStanislaus what do you mean? You mean the values? If so its like "English", "Chinese" and for section strings like "US"